# Evaluating __[POSTCOMPILE] in a sqlalchemy based flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a flask app accept queries with multiple values using sqlalchemy but am running into some issues. Trying to debug I am running into a late evaluation issue and I am trying to view the sqlalchemy query in SQL to make sure that I am querying the Postgres db correctly. So for example I am taking multiple inputs via a normal REST api like:

`url_of_api/?var=value1,value2`

That is passed to

```py
import flask as f

var = f.request.args.getlist("var")
ap = api_endpoint.search(filters=[vars.var.in_()])
```

where `search` is defined as:

```py
def search(cls, filters):
   q = Session.query(cls)   
   return q.filter(*filters).all()
```

So my issue is this: when I submit the query using sqlalchemy nothing is returned from my database. If I view `print(Str(q.filter(*filters))` the filter part of the SQL query looks like this:

```sql
WHERE vars.var IN (__[POSTCOMPILE_var_1])
```

If I "manually" query the database like so:

```sql
WHERE vars.var IN ('value1', 'value2')")
```

I get the expected return.

So my question is this: how do I force the evaluation of the `__[POSTCOMPILE_var_1]` bit that is the supplied variable values. I need to see what is being passed as a query to the database to debug but have been unable to figure out to get evaluate that. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you have a model `Var` with an attribute `vars` then you would want to pass `filters=[var.vars.in_(values)]` where `values` is the list of values in the URL query.

Comment: This was totally it. I forgot to circle back to this question. Feel free to add this as an answer and I mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else visiting this question since it comes up in google results.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql # (oracle, mysql etc)
q = sql.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={})
print(q) # the SQL it will execute but will have __[POSTCOMPILE_param_1] yet params has :param_1
print(q.params) # the parameters the sql will include
print(q.statement) has :param_1 in it which i think is far more useful
```

to have it output the exact SQL it would execute with the params included in (the values) - this is the answer OP was looking for.

```
compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}
```

so

```
q = sql.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

I dont know where this is mentioned in the sqlalchemy docs. That place is scary, but you can find some more info https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_14.html and just search for "literal_binds"